# How do I use mobile-detect.js in an Aurelia typescript app?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am not sure how to use mobile-detect.js in a Aurelia Typescript app. I figured mobile-detect should be instantiated as soon as possible so I tried to put it in main.ts like so:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mobile-detect/mobile-detect.d.ts" />

import 'MobileDetect';
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';


export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
   aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');
aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());

var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

if (md.mobile()) {

   //Do Something

}
else {

   //Do Something Else
 }
}
```

Obviously this is not the right way to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks :-)

Comment: did you try import { MobileDetect } from 'MobileDetect'

Comment: Yep. I get the following:  Error loading http://localhost:10687/views/MobileDetect.js as "MobileDetect" from http://localhost:10687/views/main.js

Comment: looks like theres an issue with your install. is it installed. do you know where the package is?

Comment: I installed it using npm:  npm install mobile-detect --save. Then I installed the typescript definition using:  tsd install mobile-detect

Answer (score 0):

So, the module loader doesn't know anything about npm modules. Try using JSPM or just doing something like import { MobileDetect } from 'node_modules/path/to/mobiledetect'

Comment: Can I load a node module using JSPM? mobile-detect is not in the JSPM repo.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. It seems when I comment out the import like the following it works.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mobile-detect/mobile-detect.d.ts" />
//import 'MobileDetect';
//import { MobileDetect } from '../../lib/mobile-detect/mobile-detect';

import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging();

    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');
    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());

    var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

    if (md.mobile()) {

        //Do Something
    }
    else {
         //Do Something
    }
}
```